# How to write a really lazy version of minimum in Idris?

Tags: idris

```
inf : Nat
inf = S inf

minimum' : Lazy Nat -> Lazy Nat -> Lazy Nat
minimum' Z b = Z
minimum' b Z = Z
minimum' (S a) (S b) = S (minimum' a b)

main : IO ()
main = do
  print $ Force $ minimum' 2 inf
```

I want to write a lazy version of minimum so that `minimum 2 inf` evaluates to be `2`, but my code seems doesn't work, it never stops, the "lazy" version of minimum doesn't make any different, so how to write an really lazy version of minimum?

Answer (score 4):

A lazy Nat is not the same as a coinductive Nat. Nat has 2 constructors, Z and S. The S needs to be transformed to take a Lazy Nat.

You can write a Nat which is coinductive like so:

```
codata CoNat : Type where
  Z : CoNat
  S : CoNat -> CoNat
```

Which should be the same as:

```
data CoNat : Type where
  Z : CoNat
  S : Inf CoNat -> CoNat
```

Make sure you use the "total" keyword or use "%default total" when working with codata. This makes Idris tell you error messages in the correct places.

You can write `minimum'` with a few different signatures if you have both CoNat and Nat. Maybe you want `CoNat -> CoNat -> CoNat`. I went with a super simple one instead:

```
total
inf : CoNat
inf = S inf

total
minimum' : Nat -> CoNat -> Nat
minimum' Z b = Z
minimum' b Z = Z
minimum' (S a) (S b) = S (minimum' a b)

total
main : IO ()
main = do
  print $ minimum' 2 inf
```

Comment: Thx a lot, that solved my problem.  but I find that making something lazy in Idris spend us so many time that people will rarely do that even Idris provided the probability in syntax level.